# How do English words change when plural in Italian?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

When an English word is used as a singular term in Italian, it is normal to use the English singular form, for example:

- un film
- un computer
- un marine spaziale
- un cowboy

When the words are used as plural terms, we can find different versions:

- due film (also due films)
- due computer (also due computers)
- due marine spaziali (also due marines spaziali)
- due cowboy (or cowboys)

I think that always using the singular is the correct way, except for the word "marines".

What is the grammatically correct declination?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While the correct, original form demands the word to be spelled with the -s (or -es, or the irregular form -ves), the Italian borrowed words should not be declined and the word remain as is.

See [this reply](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/plurale-forestierismi-adattati) from Accademia della Crusca:

> Il dubbio riguarda il trattamento dei nomi stranieri che sono entrati
> nell'italiano senza adattamento morfologico, cioè mantenendo la loro
> forma originaria. Dobbiamo premettere che, nella maggior parte dei
> casi, queste parole sono entrate in forma scritta, spesso attraverso
> l'uso giornalistico e ciò ha determinato che la forma grafica sia
> risultata predominante su quella sonora. Le parole straniere di questo
> tipo, in generale, restano invariate e, specialmente per quelle ormai
> acquisite da tempo non si pone più il problema (bar, film, quiz, tram,
> ecc.). Possono invece riaprire la questione i neologismi e le voci di
> uso raro o fortemente specialistico, che possono ricorrere,
> soprattutto nella scrittura, con il morfema finale -s, marca del
> plurale in inglese, francese, spagnolo e portoghese: proprio la
> diffusione di questa modalità di formazione del plurale nelle lingue
> europee presenta però il rischio di poter essere intesa, nella
> coscienza comune, come la modalità tipica per ottenere un plurale
> straniero e quindi di essere applicata anche a parole provenienti da
> lingue che formano il plurale in modo diverso. Si tratta quindi di
> considerare, di volta in volta, se il forestierismo che intendiamo
> utilizzare sia acquisito stabilmente e da tempo nell'italiano e in
> questo caso possiamo lasciarlo invariato, o se invece sia un
> neologismo recente o un termine fortemente specialistico e allora è
> consigliabile utilizzare il plurale della lingua d'origine.
>
> A cura di
> Raffaella Setti Redazione Consulenza Linguistica Accademia della
> Crusca

This is especially true for words that have been in the Italian vocabulary for long time (bar, film, computer). Using the correct original plural, also, is at risk of sounding too "chic" and forced; and besides, you would be applying pluralization rules that do not belong the your language, and since you can't use Italian pluralization with non-Italian words (you don't say *filmi* , for instance), keeping the word as is sounds more grammatically correct to me.

Even for newly entered words (think at "smartphone", for example) using the plural doesn't sound natural:

> - Ho visto molti smartphones ieri, ora non so quale scegliere
> - Ho visto molti smartphone ieri, ora non so quale scegliere

The second sounds better to me, but I think that the cultural and social environment can have an impact here.

Comment: Agreed, even though *smartphone* is a rather consolidated word in the language, being around since the mid 70s.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella it's the first that came into my mind...maybe because I could afford one only a few years ago :D

Comment: +1, but, nevertheless, I often hear *le brioches*, though.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis yes, you _hear_ (briosc) - the plural is omophone to the singular in this case, it seems more of a borderline case

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis as Damien said, I think *brioche* and *briosches* are homophone, when pronounced correctly . I never heard anyone pronouncing it with a final *s*.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella "Smartphone" or "smart phone" was not used in English before the mid Nineties, and in Italian even later. Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone#Origin_of_the_term).

Answer (score 7):

Personalmente non ho mai sentito la versione con la -s nel plurale che menzioni.

Il [sito della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_391.html) sconsiglia l'uso di questa versione adducendo come motivazione il semplice fatto che entrando il termine a far parte dell'italiano, non si adotta sua regola di formazione del plurale con la -s-

L'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/plurale-forestierismi-adattati) è più articolata nella risposta e, pur affermando in sostanza la stessa cosa, sostiene che quando il termine è di nuovo utilizzo, o se si riferisce ad un contesto specialistico, viene tendenzialmente usato al plurale con la forma in -s; quando è invece stabile e di vecchia data vale quanto detto sopra.

Questo perché un vocabolo specialistico o del tutto recente viene concepito come un foriesterismo piuttosto che come un'aggiunta al vocabolario della lingua.

Answer (score 3):

As already said, an English word in an Italian text should always be written in singular. There is one exception, however: in written form, if the term is written *in italics* - and thus explicitly set as a borrowed word - it il pluralized. So,

> In questi mesi ha preso piede la moda dei *selfies*.

Keep in mind that if (when) the word becomes widespread it will not be written anymore in italics, and becomes invariable.

Answer (score 2):

In Italian, the plural of English words is normally not used, so the translation of "How many computers does the university have?" is *Quanti computer ha l'università?*

Sometimes, you can see people using the plural of English words, such as in *Quanti computers ha l'università?* but that is done as joke or a semi-serious way. It's not the usual way to use a loan word.

> In quanti hotel siete stati, prima di trovare quello prenotato da Marco?

Comment: I don't think it is done as a joke or in a semi-serious way. I tend to believe it is done because people think it is the correct way of saying it. In Milan you happen to see signs in which ***boxs*** are offered for sale, along with flats...

Answer (score 2):

In italiano non si mette la -s del plurale alla fine delle parole inglesi a meno che non si tratti di neologismi di "sicura provenienza inglese". Meglio usare le regole italiane per l'italiano!

http://www.corriere.it/Rubriche/Scioglilingua/2004/23luglio.shtml